# What is the difference between pipeline & cap symbol in CSS selector?

Tags: css

I'm reading the css3 selectors, I unable to understand difference on this [lang | = en ] and [ lang ^ = en ]. Both selectors are working the same way, is there any  major difference.

Please advise me.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Where did you say you are reading about CSS3 selectors? The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) page describes the difference rather well.

Comment: I have read this from the following link " http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp "

Comment: My question is what is the difference. Both selectors are working same. For example, while I am using ^ symbol it will select beginning word of text, as well as | also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) is a little confusing. The `|=` selector has to have a dash that follows the attribute value while `^=` does not.  `|=` requires a more specific value.

```
[foo|=en] /* works for `en-` */
[foo^=en] /* works for `en` */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ortrxhq/